# Forbidden error on changing write access to sub folder in MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp, http-status-code-403

I was creating a local server environment on my mac using MAMP for one of my projects. When I opened the project using MAMP, I got the following error which is fairly expected:

```
Warning: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestProject/app/tmp/cache/models/ is not writable in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestProject/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 385
```

However when I provide write access to the `models` folder, I get a forbidden error :

```
Forbidden
Error: The requested address '/TestProject/' was not found on this server.
```

I can't figure out how does providing write access to a sub folder lead to Forbidden error to the project itself when earlier it was accessible.

The forbidden error switches to the earlier warning on removing the write access.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you enable write access? And what are the root folder permissions after that?

Comment: My root folder permissions are : drwxr-xr-x  20 user  _www   680B Aug 29 18:53 TestProject 
And for tmp folder and all its sub folders are : drwxrwxrwx  2 user  _www    68B Aug 29 19:16 tmp

Comment: OK so it doesn't make any sense.